# Почему планеты в художественных произведениях называются звёздами?

Tags: лексика

В первом абзаце "Белой гвардии" Булгакова встречается следующее предложение:

"Был он обилен летом солнцем, а зимою снегом, и  особенно высоко в небе стояли две звезды: звезда пастушеская — вечерняя Венера и красный, дрожащий Марс".

Неужто небесные тела Венера и Марс являются звёздами?

Comment: Зачем перепечатывать? Копировать не пробовали? Опечатки и незакрытые кавычки...

Comment: Почему замест длинного тире было поставлено короткое?

Comment: Правильно **так**: _Был он обилен летом солнцем, а зимою снегом, и особенно высоко в небе стояли две звезды: звезда пастушеская — вечерняя Венера и красный, дрожащий Марс._ (https://ru.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0:%D0%94%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_(%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%8F)_(%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2,_1927).djvu/5)

Answer (score 1):

Традиция называть классические планеты звездами существует во многих языках и восходит ещё ко второму тысячелетию до нашей эры. Ввиду их удаленности эти планеты представляются визуально неотличимыми от ярких звезд при наблюдении невооруженным глазом.

В частности, Венера, будучи вторым по яркости объектом в ночном небе, считалась особо яркой звездой. Однако, Венера настолько близка к Солнцу, что для наблюдателя на Земле она заходит скоро после заката и восходит незадолго до рассвета. И хотя иногда её можно увидеть невооруженным взглядом и днем, подавляющее большинство наблюдений древними астрономами делалось на закате и на рассвете, откуда и происходят оба её поэтических имени: вечерняя звезда (Геспер) и утренняя звезда (Фосфор).

Имя "звезда пастушеская" также встречается во многих языках, происходя из библейской звезды Вифлеема. Как правило имя относится именно к звезде из истории про волхвов, однако, иногда его отождествляют с Венерой в виде вечерней звезды.

Бонусный факт: в литературе также может встретиться имя Люцифер, по отношению всё к тому же астрономическому явлению. Люцифер, он же утренняя звезда, это персонификация Венеры как утренней звезды (реже как звезды вечерней), сын Авроры в римской мифологии.

Марс имеет куда меньшую яркость, но также предстает визуально как звезда красного оттенка.

Answer (score 0):

"Звездой" могут называть не только небесное тело, светящееся собственным (например, Солнце) или отражённым (например, Венера) светом, но и геометрическую фигуру на плоскости, какого-нибудь знаменитого человека, а также любой объект, напоминающий по форме "геометрическую" звезду. Подробнее о различных значениях какого-либо слова можно прочитать в толковых словарях.

Answer (score 0):

> Неужто небесные тела Венера и Марс являются звёздами?

Нет.

> Почему планеты в художественных произведениях называются звёздами?

Ну, во-первых, называют редко - и только в определенном контексте. А во-вторых, потому, что это художественное произведение.  С таким же успехом звездами могут назвать проблесковые фонари самолета. Вообще все, что на небе светится помимо луны и Солнца. Хотя Солнце-то как раз звезда, но тут размеры важны. Объект должен не просто светиться, но и быть точечным.

У Б. в процитированном отрезке, видимо, намек на то, что смотрящий не разбирается в астрономии, ему все звезда. А вообще - вопрос ниачом. Как и все вопросы, начинающиеся с "почему", но не предполагающие раскрытие истинной причинно-следственной связи. Ну вот так Булгаков захотел. Это ж литература, а не протокол вскрытия.

Для справки.
Планеты от звезд может отличить любой школьник, если посмотрит на небо чуть дольше. Планеты - движутся по небесной сфере. За это греки и назвали их "планетами" - т.е. «странниками». Или даже "подвижными светилами". Хотя последнее, кажется, не греки придумали, а какие-то там финикийцы...

Comment: И не просто "странниками", а "странствующими звездами" ;)